# Ubuntu:to which folder extract zend ce server?

Tags: ubuntu, zend

Hi i try to install zend ce on ubuntu 10.04. (I new ubuntu user)
to which folder extract zend ce server (tar)?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the official **Ubuntu packages** for Zend.
Searching for it on my Ubuntu 10.04 Server showed the followin packages:

```
libzend-framework-php                                                                  - a simple, straightforward, open-source software framework for PHP 5
zend-framework                                                                         - a simple, straightforward, open-source software framework for PHP 5
zend-framework-bin                                                                     - a simple, straightforward, open-source software framework for PHP 5
zendframework                                                                          - powerful PHP framework
zendframework-bin                                                                      - binary scripts for zendframework
```

Of those you need either zend-framework or zendframework - am not sure which though.
Install it then using the following command:

```
sudo aptitude install zendframework
```

---

If you are planning to **install it manually** and not via apt-get or aptitude (i.e. with the offical Ubuntu packages) place it in the following folder:

```
/opt/
```

That, I guess, would be the Ubuntu way for manually installed servers. If you do that you should also provide a symbolic link that points to the current version.
So if the installation would look like this

```
/opt/zend-someversion-xxx/...
```

You should add a symlink called 'zend' (or whatever seems reasonable) that points to this installation.

```
ln -s zend-someversion-xxx zend
```

This has the effect that your zend installation will always be available as

```
/opt/zend/
```

even if you later upgrade to a different version. (Which would most likely change the name of the folder and screw up config...)

Answer (score 1):

I would install it from the repositories using a package manager. That way you can keep it up to date with bug fixes and security patches automatically.

I'm not sure [which package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zend&searchon=names&suite=lucid&section=all) you need, but the installation would be similar to:

```
sudo apt-get install zendframework
```

Comment: yes, but its not last version!!!!